# Flux through a Möbius strip

Tags: electromagnetism, differential-geometry

A friend of mine asked me what is the flux of the electric field (or any vector field like 
$$
\vec r=(x,y,z)\mapsto \frac{\vec r}{|r|^3}
$$
(where $|r|=(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{1/2}$) through a Möbius strip. It seems to me there are no ways to compute it in the "standard" way because the strip is not orientable, but if I think about the fact that such a strip *can* indeed be built (for example using a thin metal layer), I also think that an answer *must* be mathematically expressible.

Searching on wikipedia I found [that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobius_resistor):

> A Möbius resistor is an electrical component made up of two conductive surfaces separated by a dielectric material, twisted 180° and connected to form a Möbius strip. *It provides a resistor which has no residual self-inductance, meaning that it can resist the flow of electricity without causing magnetic interference at the same time.*

How can I relate the highlighted phrase to some known differential geometry (physics, analysis?) theorem?

Thanks a lot!

---

Now, I'm convinced that there are no way to apply Gauss' law since there are no ways to bound a portion of space with a Moöbius strip. Nonetheless I would like to "see" some equations showing me that "[the Möbius resistor] can resist the flow of electricity without causing magnetic interference at the same time".

Answer (score 11):

Assuming the material of the strip is a good conductor any charges, and currents, on the strip must end up on the boundary. This is true at least in the limit of small applied e.m.f So its not really Gauss', but Ampere's law you're looking for here:

$$ \int_{\partial M} I \cdot \mathrm dl = \Phi_B $$

i.e. the line integral of the current $I$ around the boundary $\partial M$ of the Mobius strip $M$. This quantity is actually a topological invariant of the manifold (in this case $M$) under question. For the Mobius strip it is as can be seen to be zero by starting at any given point on the boundary and evaluating the integral as one moves along the edge for one complete cycle.

[image]

<sup>[Image source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:M%C3%B6bius_resistor.svg)</sup>

<strike>**Note**: Some of the arrows are incorrect. Think of the strip as a freeway with the vertical axis running through its center, where cars drive only on the edges. You can divide the edge into parts "upper" and "lower", then the current should be circulating one way in the "upper" half and the opposite way in the "lower" half, changing directions at the place where the "interchange" is located. Label accordingly.</strike>

Comment: The currents in the picture are correct. The "inner" part is in contact with the + , the "outer" with the -. At the twist, there is a switch between "inner" and "outer".

Comment: The arrows are incorrect if you take the current in the strip to be running along the edges, instead of in the interior of the strip itself. So, I guess they are correct in the original context of the figure, but incorrect for my purposes.

Comment: I didn't understand if you're considering the currents going through the boundary of the strip or along the z-axis (I suppose that in that picture -I found it on wikipedia too- the central circle of the strip lies on the plane xy, and its center is in the origin (0,0,0))

Comment: I mean, along the axis through an infinite line crossed by current

Comment: @Tetrapharmakon yes that is the orientation of the strip. The strip lies in the xy plane and the z-axis is the vertical direction.

Comment: I was saying, are you considering an "infinite" line crossed by current and the boundary of the strip intertwining it twice? Or something like *the boundary itself* is crossed by current?

Comment: I have to say I don't understand this answer at all. I'll try rereading it few times, perhaps it will help :-)

Comment: First, why should there be no current in the interior of the strip? That just doesn't make sense. E.g. in the original context of the picture with those electrodes attached, the current would flow through the interior. Second, I don't understand *[the current should be] changing directions at the place where the "interchange" is located*. Why? To me it seems obvious that it will go the same way both on the bottom and on the top. Or are you talking about relative orientation w.r.t. the origin?

Comment: So if I understood your construction, you've completely lost the topological information and obtained just twofold cover of the circle (i.e. you projected on the base of the fibre bundle). This is equivalent to the standard flow in the circle and is completely uninteresting and unrelated to the question. Please, try to clarify these points.

Comment: You might be right @marek. I might have made a big boo boo. Let me get back to you on this one.

Comment: @ Marek, go to the website about the [Möbius resistor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobius_resistor). There are two strips insulated by some dielectric and then joined to form a Möbius strip. That's why there is no current "inside the strip" because there are really two metalic strips, the inside being a non-conductor.

Comment: @Raskolnikov: I think there is a potential confusion here when talking about inside. I am talking about *two* dimensional Möbius strip with one-dimensional boundary (which is what space_cadet is talking about too, if I understood his construction properly). You are talking about the real three-dimensional object with two-dimensional strips attached, I suppose?

Comment: Well, it only makes sense to talk about what is possible to be made into a resistor. So I talk precisely about the resistor that is presented on the wiki page. That is, two metallic strips separated by a dielectricum and then the ends are joined together after twisting so that the "outer" strip connects to the "inner" strip and visa versa. But it makes sense to consider a loop that goes twice round but taking once the "inner" path and then the "outer". Not sure anymore what space_cadet has in mind.

Comment: *it makes sense to consider a loop that goes twice round but taking once the "inner" path and then the "outer"* - @raskolnikov that is what I'm talking about, if that helps. And, thanks for the clarification about whether or not there is a current in the "inside of the strip".