# Electric field and potential in Möbius band

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, electricity

Suppose I have a Möbius band with uniform density charge $\sigma$. ¿What would happen since is not possible to find the electric field or potential in its surface as:

$$ \vec{E} = \iint \frac{K_e dq}{r²} d \breve{r}$$
$$ V = -\int \vec{E} \cdot d\breve{r} $$

beacuse the surface is not parametrizable? ¿At least is there any possibility that the band remains charged and/or for predicting the electric field?

Comment: 1. The fact that the Möbius strip is a one-sided nonorientable surface does not mean that it is not parametrizable. 2. Your formulas do not make sense.

Comment: @Hyperon ok, and what are the correct formulas?

Comment: @Hyperon And more important: whats the sense of making a parametrization for this case? wouldn't that mean that at any point the electric field vector could aim in two possible directions? how is that possible?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/567969/fields-due-to-m%C3%B6bius-strip Or perhaps this diploma thesis: https://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0411137.pdf Also I faintly remember reading a related paper co-authored by Hehl, but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

A (uniform) charge distribution sitting on a (finite) two-dimensional manifold (orientable or not) constitutes a perfectly well defined volume charge density $\rho(\mathbf{x})$ containing a delta function to confine it to the two-dimensional surface. If the Möbius strip confuses you, just cut it along the line where it had been glued together. This does not change the charge distribution and you can deal with an orientable surface. Compute the scalar potental using the standard formula $V(\mathbf{x})= \int \! d^3 \!y \, \rho(\mathbf{y})/|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}|$ and finally the electric field $\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{x}) = - \mathbf{\nabla} V(\mathbf{x})$, being uniquely determined at any point $\mathbf{x}$ outside of the charge distribution. Of course, as a consequence of the Gauss law, the normal component of the electric field exhibits a discontinuity when you pass from one side of the surface to the other.